# AOP @Before method not calling

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Could someone help me why it is not working,

**CustomerService**

```
package com.aop.sample;

public interface CustomerService {

    void addCustomer();

    String addCustomerReturnValue();

    void addCustomerThrowException() throws Exception;

    void addCustomerAround(String name);

}
```

**CustomerServiceImpl**

```
package com.aop.sample;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService{

    public void addCustomer(){
        System.out.println("addCustomer() is running ");
    }

    public String addCustomerReturnValue(){
        System.out.println("addCustomerReturnValue() is running ");
        return "abc";
    }

    public void addCustomerThrowException() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("addCustomerThrowException() is running ");
        throw new Exception("Generic Error");
    }

    public void addCustomerAround(String name){
        System.out.println("addCustomerAround() is running, args : " + name);
    }   
}
```

**LoggingAspect**

```
package com.aop.sample;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before; 

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.aop.sample.CustomerService.addCustomer(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("******");
    }

}
```

**TestRun**

```
package com.aop.sample;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");


        CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService) appContext.getBean("customerServiceImpl");
        customerService.addCustomer();

    }

}
```

**app-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aop.sample" />

</beans>
```

-My Current output is -

```
addCustomer() is running
```

-Expected Out put-

```
logBefore() is running!
hijacked : addCustomer
******
addCustomer() is running
```

Kindly advice, What I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate your `LoggingAspect` class with `@Component` so a bean can be generated

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
```

and registered. Alternatively, add a `<bean>` element in the context file for `LoggingAspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the app-context.xml if you dont want to use annotations.

```
<bean name="loggingAspect" class="com.aop.sample.LogginAspect"/>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-at-aspectj